# Putting a tag in aligned environment

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

I want to set a counter in the following two lines (to the right)

```
\[
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& u_t = H(x,t,Du)&\text{ in }& \mathbb{R}^n\times (0,T)  \\\\
& u(x,0)=u_0(x) & \text{ in } &\mathbb{R}^n
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]
```

the problem is that I cannot add a counter in aligned environment and I cannot use an equation environment inside mathmode.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use a counter inside the environment? Why should it be impossible to set a counter inside the env and use `\tag*{\arabic{foo}}`, `foo` being the counter?

Comment: Does that give errors and what errors does it give?

Comment: It does not allow me to add a tag inside aligned, I used something like this `\newcommand\addtag{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}`
but it only work for the equation environment

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small simplification of the code with the `overload` option of `empheq`, and a variant if you want to emulate the `numcases` environment. Also it's pointless to load `amsmath` as `empheq` loads `mathtools` which loads it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}[left=\empheqlbrace]
 & u_t = H(x,t,Du) & \quad&\text{in }\mathbb{R}^n × (0,T) \\[\medskipamount]
  & u(x,0)=u_0(x) & &\text{in } \mathbb{R}^n
\end{alignat}
\vskip 1cm

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}[left=\empheqlbrace]
 & u_t = H(x,t,Du) &\quad & \text{in }\mathbb{R}^n × (0,T) \\[\medskipamount]
 & u(x,0)=u_0(x) & & \text{in } \mathbb{R}^n
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion it makes little sense having two numbers for a single mathematical object (the system of equations). Anyway, if you really want this, use `empheq` (and `alignat` as the inner environment, because `align` would spread the parts too much):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}
& u_t = H(x,t,Du) &\quad\text{in }& \mathbb{R}^n\times (0,T) \\[\medskipamount]
& u(x,0)=u_0(x)   &\quad\text{in }& \mathbb{R}^n
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]